# Viewing and clearing all user specific permissions in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

We are cleaning up the permissions in our Sitecore instance and we are running in to users that were granted specific access over the years. Now I would like to put all of our permissions in to roles and only grant rights via roles.

**Is there a way to see the rights specifically assigned to a user?** We have a small enough number of users that I could fix this manually, but the security viewer shows the cumulative permissions from user rights and role rights.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  You could probably write a query to check for a specific user ID in the __Security field.  I'll go try this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query idea actually worked.  So you can use Xpath Builder (in Dev Center) for this.  It will be a little slow, but gives you the items:

/sitecore/content/myRoot//*[contains(@__Security,'username')]

Comment: Cool idea... I took it and tested it within Sitecore Rocks and worked as well. 

select  @@ID as ID, @@Name as Name, @@Path as Path, @__Security from /sitecore/content/home//*[contains(@__Security,'xxxx')];

Comment: This ended up being the simplest solution for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Josh,
I just released a little script that should help you get moving on this. This script will show you all values of the __security field and allow you to reset them all. You will need to modify to reset for a specific user.

http://seankearney.com/post/Sitecore-Security-Report-and-Reset.aspx

Comment: To customize this for your needs, you can look at modifying line 56 to check if your user is 'contained' within the value.

Comment: This is awesome. I will test it today or tomorrow and come back to give you the credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Figured I would throw this out there after some testing with Rocks.

You can report on security from Sitecore Rocks (as mentioned in my comment to Bryan):

`select  @@ID as ID, @@Name as Name, @@Path as Path, @__Security from /sitecore/content/home//*[contains(@__Security,'xxxx')];`

You can also reset the security field with a query too!

`update set @__Security = "" from /sitecore/content/home//*[contains(@__Security,'xxxx')];`