# Sitecore - Is there a way to reset all Access Rights in User Manager or Security Editor?

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I currently have a user whose Access Rights are messed up and I'd like to reset them.  I could be blind but does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the only way I've been able to do this is to go into the Security Editor, select the user, then open every item in the tree and unset every access right manually to the default setting of Inherited.

For instance,  there are at least a Read/Write/Rename/Create/Delete/Administer/Inheritance permission on just the Home item alone.  Each permission has one of the following states: Inherited/Allowed/Denied/Item vs. Descendant Right/Protected/Not Applicable.  If any of those are set, manually unset it.  So, if it were set to Allowed, you'd click the green check mark which would unset it from Allowed (I guess you could argue I'm setting it to Inherited).

To get back to square one, everything should be set back to Inherited.

Comment: You really shouldn't be setting access right against a user, instead you should set them against roles, that way all you would have had to do was to add/remove the user from the roles.

Comment: @jammykam - I respect the spirit of what you're saying but this one I inherited.  Creating roles and assigning access rights to those is far superior and much more maintainable.

Comment: Fair enough, sometimes you just have to deal with what you have. I saw your other related question, I think you reliase you'll give yourself a much easier time if you move the permissions over to roles.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to reset the user rights.

The only way I can think of is deleting the user and create a new one, or write a script that loops to the tree or retrieves al items that the current user has rights on and resets the rights for this user.

Comment: I actually tried deleting the user, then recreating it.  If you use the same info when re-creating the user and then look at the Access Viewer or Security Editor that user will still have the previous access rights.  This was pretty crazy to me!

Comment: I thought it would be like that, because users are identified by name, not by ID although I hoped that Sitecore would remove the security settings when a user was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Security of an item is stored within the `__security` field on the item itself. Furthermore, security is stored by the name of the user or role, not by an ID. Deleting a user/role will not modify any item that references that user/role so you effectively get orphaned access rights.

I had created a script years ago that will report on (and reset) the security of items. It is available from my [blog post](http://seankearney.com/post/Sitecore-Security-Report-and-Reset.aspx) and I referenced it within this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614776/viewing-and-clearing-all-user-specific-permissions-in-sitecore). You should be able to modify that script to remove a single user's rights.